# How do I echo interval between two numbers?

Tags: php

I have two numbers:

```
110009
114993
```

How do I echo in PHP all the numbers between this interval?

```
110009
110010
110011
110012
....
```

Comment: `foreach(range($num1, $num2) as $it) { echo $it; }`?

Comment: You can do it even shorter without a loop: `echo implode(PHP_EOL, range(110009, 114993));`. But as been pointed out, a `for`-loop would be preferred since it's not particularly memory efficient to use `range()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `range()` function.

```php
$start = 110009;
$end = 114993;

foreach (range($start, $end) as $val) {
    echo $val."\n<br />";
}
```

Or a regular `for` loop incremented by 1

```php
$start = 110009;
$end = 114993;

for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
    echo $i."\n<br />";
}
```

Comment: I think it's a good idea to explain memory difference between these solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 110009; $i <= 114993; $i++) {
    echo $i . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `range` and `implode`:

```
echo implode("\n", range(110009, 114993));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range` to accomplish your goal.

```
$r = range( 110009, 114993, 1 );
```

Then to print the values

```
foreach( $r as $i )echo $i;
```

Comment: Although it's a nice solution, problem is the array with all this values will be stored in memory. Simple `for` loop uses less memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function that will output the range:

```
function output_number_range($start, $end) {
    for ($n = ($start < $end ? $start : $end); $n <= ($end > $start ? $end : $start); $n++) {
        echo $n . '<br>';
    }
}

output_number_range(36, 3);
```

The above uses a simple for loop and the two ternarys allow you to call the function with the biggest or smallest number in the desired range in any order.